# Mapping/function. Show that $M\subseteq f^{-1}(f(M))$.

Tags: functions

> Let $f:A\to B$ be a mapping. Show that for all subsets $M$ of $A$ satisfies 
>   \begin{equation}
> M\subseteq f^{-1}(f(M)).
> \end{equation}
>   Give an example that $f^{-1}(f(M))$ doesn't need to be equal to $M$.

Any hint where to start?

Comment: Can you add some detail about what you've done so far?

Comment: Take $x \in M$, then $f(x) \in f(M)$ ...

Comment: The equallity stands if $f$ is 1-1.If not, it may not stand. For example when $f(x)=x^2$ and $A=[-1,1]$

Comment: @egreg. Some hours later I still have no idea what to do the right way. I could only say that $x\in f^{-1}(f(M))\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in f(M)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the basics; when in doubt, create a new name for a complex object.

If $N\subseteq B$, then an element $x\in A$ is in $f^{-1}(N)$ if and only if $f(x)\in N$.

Set $N=f(M)$; if $x\in M$, then $f(x)\in f(M)=N$, by definition. Therefore $x\in f^{-1}(N)$. Now $f^{-1}(N)=f^{-1}(f(M))$ just by substituting symbols.

Now consider $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{4,5\}$ and define $f(1)=4$, $f(2)=4$, $f(3)=5$. Consider $M=\{1\}$. What can you say about $f^{-1}(f(M))$?

Comment: Thanks for answering! If $f(M)=4$ since $M=\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ then $f^{-1}(f(M)) = f^{-1}(4)=1$ or $f^{-1}(4)=2$. I understand your point now. Thanks once again!

Comment: @AjmalW No: $f(M)=\{4\}$; but $f^{-1}(f(M))=\{1,2\}$, because also $f(2)\in f(M)$.